# Generate apk using gradle & Nodejs

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to generate apk files using Nodejs along with Gradle with the [NodeJs sync process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation) and the following code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;
exec(`cd ~/appFolder && ./gradlew assembleRelease`);
```

Now please note that when I execute:

```
cd ~/appFolder && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

from the command line, it works perfectly and I get build successful. But when I run the javascript above, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in 
the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Note that I did set ANDROID_HOME and the local.properties file exist in the app folder.
Thank you very much.